# Calling Secured Azure function (Google auth) from React Native

Tags: azure, react-native, authentication, azure-functions

**Solution:**

Client and API architecture.

Client: React native (android)

API: Azure functions with Authentication enabled (Microsoft, Google)
[image]

**Reproduction steps:**

Inside react native, using [react-native app auth](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth) i successfully get the idToken and accessToken from Google. I then make a post to my api to attempt to get the authentication token with axios:

[image]

It then gives: Request failed with status code 401

**Documentation following:**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-customize-sign-in-out#validate-tokens-from-providers

Note i've also tried with Microsoft but same situation. successfully get access token and id token but when trying to get the authentication token from Azure functions get a 401.